# SSL Certificate Install in IIS7 from PFX issue

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

I was following along this list for installing an SSL certificate and got stuck on step 12/13.  Apparently there is no 'director security tab' in IIS 7.x so I'm not sure how to proceed.  In my IIS Server Certificates panel - I can currently see the OLD SSL certificate which expires in a few days, and below it is the new one that expires next year, they are both issued to the same domain.  How can I proceed ?  Any help is appreciated!

Here is the list that I was using - (I'm stuck on step 13)

```
Importing your Certificate/Private Key in IIS (from .pfx file format)
1.) Start > Run
2.) Type in MMC and click GO
3.) Go into the Console Tab (or File) > select Add/Remove Snap-in
4.) Click on Add > Double Click on Certificates and click on Add > OK
5.) Select Computer Account
6.) Select Local Computer
7.) Click the + to Expand the Certificates Consol Tree
8.) Right click on the Personal Certificates Store (folder)
9.) Choose > ALL TASKS > Import
10.) Follow the Certificate Import Wizard to import your Primary Certificate from the .pfx file. When prompted, choose to automatically place the certificates in the certificate stores based on the type of the certificate.
11.) Close the MMC console. In the case that you are prompted, it is not necessary to save the changes made to the MMC console.
12.) In your IIS manager, right-click on the site that you would like to use the certificate and select properties.
13.) Click on the Directory Security Tab and hit the Server Certificate Button. This will start the server certificate wizard.
14.) If you are asked what you want to do with the current certificate on the site, choose to remove it, finish the wizard, and click the server certificate button to run the wizard again.
15.) Choose to 'Assign an existing certificate' to the site and choose the new certificate that you just imported.
16.) Finish the certificate wizard.
17.) Restart the server.
```

Comment: Why not just go into the bindings for the site, select the 443 binding and apply the cert there?

Comment: @DanBig Thanks, that worked perfectly.  I just didn't know how to proceed, as this is my first SSL Certificate install.

Comment: I set it as an answer, please upvote/accept.

Comment: The list above it not only for an older version of IIS (5, 6.x) is is also wrong. When finding such lists, always make sure they apply to the version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

After importing the certificate through the mmc snap-in, go into IIS, open the bindings for the site, select the 443 binding and apply the cert there.